# java JSONObject initialization returen java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java Heap

Tags: java, json

i have this JSON object i'm getting from an open socket:

```
{
 "action" : "login",
 "id" : "1554",
 "name": "asaf",
 "lat" : "26.519966",
 "long" : "-4.151437",
 "radius":"0", 
  "data":[
          {"id":"12345"},
          {"id":"1234"},
          {"id":"123"}
         ]
}
```

inside my code when i'm doing:

```
stream = new JSONObject(input);
```

(input is my object from the socket)
i'm getting the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java Heap..

can't really understand why...

stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Worker for Socket:     Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=52571,localport=9001]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java     heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:117)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:205)
at ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:80)
```

Comment: post a stacktrace, please.

Comment: Please write your complete code.

Comment: this it my complete code...
line 80 at ServerWorker is stream = new JSONObject(input);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you can do like this if your JSON response is large:

```
stream = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(input)):
```

Comment: follow this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842201/out-of-memory-error-when-putting-large-json-inputstream-to-string