# Parsing a large json in android of 11 MB

Tags: android, json, parsing, jackson, gson

I am facing a problem in parsing a large JSON of about 11MB in android with GSON and Jackson. The issue is that out of memory error exception occurs and also heap size is not enough to accomplish this process.
This is my Paper Model Class

```
public class Paper {

public int primaryKey;

public String title;

public int entry;

public Boolean favourite;

public String comment;

public int opt;

public int score;
}
```

This is my Response Model Class

```
public class Response {

public List<Paper> papers;

}
```

This is my JSON String

```
{"Paper":[[{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A Fully Intraocular 0.0169mm<sup>2<\/sup>/pixel 512-Channel Self-Calibrating Epiretinal Prosthesis in 65nm CMOS","primaryKey":3,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A Scalable 2.9mW 1Mb/s eTextiles Body Area Network Transceiver with Remotely Powered Sensors and Bi-Directional Data Communication","primaryKey":14,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 0.18Âµm CMOS SoC for a 100m-Range 10fps 200Ã—96-Pixel Time-of-Flight Depth Sensor","primaryKey":20,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 12b 1.6GS/s 40mW DAC in 40nm CMOS with >70dB SFDR over Entire Nyquist Bandwidth","primaryKey":26,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"All-Digital Hybrid Temperature Sensor Network for Dense Thermal Monitoring","primaryKey":49,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"32Gb/s Data-Interpolator Receiver with 2-Tap DFE in 28nm CMOS","primaryKey":51,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 93% Efficiency Reconfigurable Switched-Capacitor DC-DC Converter Using On-Chip Ferroelectric Capacitors","primaryKey":60,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 45nm CMOS Near-Field Communication Radio with 0.15A/m RX Sensitivity and 4mA Current Consumption in Card Emulation Mode","primaryKey":61,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1}]]}
```

I don't know where i did a mistake. i getting null for the lise of papers.

Comment: you should post the code you are using to deserialize

Comment: It's full of different Objects, so that i can't pass it onto single class.

http://206.81.33.5:8080/Conf411/Conf411Service?command=get&id=ISMRM2012

Coding very huge to accomodate. please go through above link and give some idea for any one particular class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Out of memory error when putting large JSON (InputStream) to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842201/out-of-memory-error-when-putting-large-json-inputstream-to-string)

Answer (score 4):

Use a streaming parser and try to process the content as you read it, before the full input has been read. This way you can avoid to hold the full structure in memory.

For example if your input JSON is a huge array, you could process the input element by element.

Comment: It's full of different Objects, so that i can't pass it onto single class. [JSON URL](http://206.81.33.5:8080/Conf411/Conf411Service?command=get&id=ISMRM2012) Coding very huge to accomodate. please go through above link and give some idea for any one particular class.

Comment: Take a look at the Gson streaming doc, which explains how to mix streaming & data binding: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/), check the databinding api (`new Genson().deserialize(json, ToClass.class)`) or using directly the streaming api.

It depends on what you want to do.
If you need all data in memory then there is not much choice, you need to increase it.
If you can process things as you are reading it and dont need it always in memory, then it will work fine with the streaming api (very performant and uses extremly few memory).

**EDIT** 
Solutions

1. You want to use databinding so you have less work to do. First have a look at this project https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo it allows you to generate java bean classes based on a json example. When you have your generated classes just do `new Genson().deserialize(json, MyGeneratedClass.class);` if you are doing multiple ser/deser, you should reuse Genson instances for better performances.
2. If you don't want to use 1), if the structure changes at runtime (this would prevent from generating the classes), or you still have memory issues use [Gensons streaming api](http://genson.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/owlike/genson/stream/ObjectReader.html).
   It is memory efficient, performant and easy to use.

Comment: It's full of different Objects, so that i can't pass it onto single class. [JSON URL](http://206.81.33.5:8080/Conf411/Conf411Service?command=get&id=ISMRM2012) Coding very huge to accomodate. please go through above link and give some idea for any one particular class.

Comment: @Praveen I have updated my answer with some more details. If it is still not enough I will try to provide you some examples but it would help if you posted your code.

Comment: i can able to use which your are telling in java. but not possible in android. since android having the large heap size.

Comment: @Praveen You mean you tried solution 1 and worked on a computer? If 1 does not work on android the only remaining solution is 2. Try it