# How to Parse JSONArray using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing a large json in android of 11 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412676/parsing-a-large-json-in-android-of-11-mb)

I am facing a problem in parsing a large JSON of about 11MB in android with GSON and Jackson. The issue is that out of memory error exception occurs and also heap size is not enough to accomplish this process. This is my Paper Model Class

```
public class Paper {
    public int primaryKey;
    public String title;
    public int entry;
    public Boolean favourite;
    public String comment;
    public int opt;
    public int score;
}
```

This is my Response Model Class

```
public class Response {
    public List<Paper> papers;
}
```

This is my JSON String

```
{"Paper":[[{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A Fully Intraocular 0.0169mm<sup>2<\/sup>/pixel 512-Channel Self-Calibrating Epiretinal Prosthesis in 65nm CMOS","primaryKey":3,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A Scalable 2.9mW 1Mb/s eTextiles Body Area Network Transceiver with Remotely Powered Sensors and Bi-Directional Data Communication","primaryKey":14,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 0.18Âµm CMOS SoC for a 100m-Range 10fps 200Ã—96-Pixel Time-of-Flight Depth Sensor","primaryKey":20,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 12b 1.6GS/s 40mW DAC in 40nm CMOS with >70dB SFDR over Entire Nyquist Bandwidth","primaryKey":26,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"All-Digital Hybrid Temperature Sensor Network for Dense Thermal Monitoring","primaryKey":49,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"32Gb/s Data-Interpolator Receiver with 2-Tap DFE in 28nm CMOS","primaryKey":51,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 93% Efficiency Reconfigurable Switched-Capacitor DC-DC Converter Using On-Chip Ferroelectric Capacitors","primaryKey":60,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1},{"abstract":"Not Available","title":"A 45nm CMOS Near-Field Communication Radio with 0.15A/m RX Sensitivity and 4mA Current Consumption in Card Emulation Mode","primaryKey":61,"entry":9,"score":-1,"comment":null,"favourite":false,"opt":1}]]}
```

I don't know where i did a mistake. i getting null for the lise of papers.

Comment: 11 MB of JSON in Android? it's significantly higher, any reason why are you trying to parse so large amount of json?

Comment: @Pradeep This application is an offline supporting application. we will download once and parse from that file.

Comment: `Paper` and `papers` are not the same, if you rename `papers` to `Paper` in the Java part, or even better `Paper` to `papers` in the JSON, there's big chance it will work better.

Comment: you need to post code, where you are parsing it

Answer (score 1):

> I am facing a problem in parsing a large JSON of about 11MB in android
>   with GSON and Jackson.

it will be very hard to Download and Parse it. 11MB is too High.

Alternatives that you can Use is :

> you can Modify your Webservice to have a partition with Counter like
>   **`counter=1,2,3....`** meanse Make a WS in a way that First 1000 Records
>   Come for counter=1 after Parsing it another Data will come for
>   **counter=2** and Parse it and So on..

this will help you to sort out your problem Some How.

Comment: Except there's no reason to do this. Gson supports streaming, as do other JSON parsers.